# Алгоритм поиска пути A* для группы ячеек

Tags: алгоритм, искусственный-интеллект

Здравствуйте,

Написал алгоритм поиска А* в базовой форме для нахождения пути из 1 ячейки в другую, но мне требуется поиск для группы таких ячеек (т.е составной фигуры из таких ячеек). Можете подсказать, есть ли возможность как-то расширить алгоритм, или надо представлять сразу эту фигуру в виде одной ячейки и перекраивать карту алгоритма под нее?

На данный момент, я имею что-то вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно развить это до этого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните, что Вы имеете в виду под составной фигурой из ячеек? Алгоритм должен только по определённым ячейкам искать путь? Надеюсь нет, а то это не сложно.

Comment: как вы определяете может ли ячейка/группа ячеек переместиться в соседнюю ячейку?

Comment: @Grundy У меня есть список, где содержатся "закрытые" ячейки. Поэтому, при итерации A*, когда рассматриваются соседи ячейки с наименьшей стоимостью, я просто не беру во внимание соседей, которые находятся в этом списке. Повторюсь, алгоритм у меня работает пока только для 1 ячейки, а хотелось бы для группы.

Comment: один из вариантов - проверять что все ячейки фигуры не попадают на закрытые

Comment: @AivanF. Добавил графические объяснения, надеюсь, теперь вам стало понятно, что я имею ввиду. Мне непонятно, можно ли, например, для моего примера с фигурой из 2 ячеек работать дальше с моим разбиением карты на ячейки. Или же стоит как-то перекроить карту и за 1 ячейку уже брать целый прямоугольник, чтобы фигура полностью вошла в него.

Comment: @Grundy Дело даже не в обходе препятствий, а как сделать, чтобы она двигалась неразрывно. Вопрос в том, что делают с a* алгоритмом, если объект занимает больше чем 1 ячейка на поле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, решение получилось довольно частным, но какое есть. Решено было создать  объект ComplexFigure для фигур из группы ячеек, который бы включал в себя эту группу ячеек и имел схожие с ними параметры (Оценка пройденного пути, оценка пути до цели и ссылка на родительскую фигуру). Оценка пути до цели для него рассчитывается, как сумма таких оценок для входящих в него ячеек.

Здесь и кроется некий подвох: каждая ячейка должна знать в какую именно позицию она должна попасть в итоговой фигуре. То есть, имея фигуру из 2 ячеек, как в примере, первая ячейка стремится именно к первой позиции, а вторая ко второй.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если фигуре пришлось как-то перевернуться в процессе прохода к цели, то ей придется перевернуться еще раз, чтобы ячейки заняли именно свои позиции.

В остальном, все происходит как с 1 ячейкой. Когда рассматриваются соседи для фигуры с наименьшей стоимостью пути, для каждого направления движения рассматриваются соседи каждой отдельной ячейки в фигуре. И если хоть одна ячейка не может сместится в сторону этого соседа, то он сразу считается непроходным для целой фигуры.